# How to render mp4 file from blob url?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm using [flutter dropzone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dropzone) package, how can I get the mp4 file from blob url or uint8list?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get the mp4 file from blob url or uint8list?

You can not get a reference of a `File` object pointing to the dropped File. That is simply not possible in a web environment.

But as you have already pointed out correctly, you can get the file contents as a `Uint8List` or `Stream<List<int>>`. Should not really make a difference since the content of the File is usually all one cares about.